# jquery datable style not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have included all the necessary libraries, used datatable with proper syntax, but for some reason I don't know why the tables style is broken. here is my code,

```
<h3>List of Categories</h3>
<table id="testCategory" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Category ID</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
       <th>Created On</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#testCategory").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/testcategories",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    { "data": "testCategoryId" },
                    { "data": "testCategoryName" },
                    { "data": "createdOn" },
                    { "data": "createdBy" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

and the output shows like below. Here you can see all the libraries I linked. Is there a syntactical problem or did I miss any libraries? I even tried it with original bootstrap rather than this bootstrap theme.

[image]

Comment: Please check the bootstrap version, and dataTable.bootstrap.css version. You may need to include the compatible version of css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright so i have figured it out at last. i am using bootstrap 4 so i have to use `dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css`.

Comment: If this has solved your question then accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write ajax function inside Datatable , write it separately & call datatable like this,

$("#testCategory").dataTable();

May be this will helpful for you !!